# Get error when getting related youtube videos using Youtube API

Tags: r, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get videos related to some youtube videos.

I used the Youtube API and get the following url

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?relatedToVideoId=F608hzn_ygo&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

However, I get the following error message

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The incorrect argument is the "relatedToVideoId". I just find out that the relatedToVideoId argument was removed.Is there another way to get the related videos?

Someone can give a direction?